# Are questions on Apple-like hardware for PCs on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-scope

I flagged question [Are there any non-Apple multi-touch trackpads on the market?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27360/are-there-any-non-apple-multi-touch-trackpads-on-the-market) as "off-topic" and also commented that it probably should be migrated to Super User. The flag was declined with a reason that the question is on-topic.

> I love the Apple trackpad with its multi-touch gestures. I want to buy a MacBook Pro primarily because of this. I am a student though and it seems to be very expensive for me.

In other words the OP likes a multi-touch trackpad, **but** would like to buy a PC because MacBook Pro is too expensive for his/her budget.

> Hence I was wondering if any other company except for Apple provides a trackpad, or is it only available on Apple devices?

I admit, this part of the question might make it on-topic: **Are multi-touch trackpads** (there is no mention the question is only about Magic Trackpad) **only available for Apple devices?**

> Also if this is the case then is there a software that can be used to mimic the Apple trackpad on an ordinary laptop? I am using Synaptic but is not the same.

Question is: how to get MacBook Pro's touchpad's functionalities on a PC-laptop's touchpad.

And finally, confirming the OP is looking for a solution for Windows:

> i want a hardware and software package. Are there any drivers in windows that will understand the trackpad movements?

All in all, the questions are:

- Is Apple the sole provider of multi-touch trackpads (on-topic)

  - If this is true, then how to have the multi-touch functions on a PC laptop's bundled trackpad? (off-topic)
  - If this is false, then which PC-companies have laptops that have multi-touch features (off-topic)

Hidden (not asked, but could be involved in answers) workaround questions:

- Are there external multi-touch trackpads for PC laptop? (off-topic)
- Can I use the Magic Trackpad on a PC laptop? (on-topic)

---

**My question is:** should the question be heavily edited or migrated to Super User? Or am I wrong enough to just let the question be?

Comment: I had the same reservation when I read that question. I'm still "new" (as in actively participating here) but my take is how does an answer to this question help future readers? And specific to this question, even if an answer is viable (non-Apple sourced multi-touch hardware), will it work with Apple without device driver support?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, that is off topic, sorry. When I read it for some reason I thought the asker was looking for a non-Apple multitouch trackpad *to use with a Mac* (which would be on topic), but in rereading the question that's clearly not the case.

Thanks for bringing this back up. I wish I could undo the flag decline, but from what I can tell those are permanent once cast.

Comment: Hey, it happens. Think of I just made a sophisticated CAPTCHA on you and by making an error, you just proved to be human. :-)